# timestamp with 31 days every month

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp, hex

I have some hex timestamps. I try to convert them into expected date.

For example,

```
#ReferenceData
 
  Raw Data           Expected Date
E2 E8 24 26      2019-11-29 20:45:22
```

For the next expected date, I just minus the current data with the raw data of #ReferenceData to get the difference in seconds and add the difference in second to the expected date of #ReferenceData to get the next expected date. But unfortunately the resulting data seems to be different from the expected one starting from December 2019

```
Raw Data             Result            Expected Date
E2 E8 24 26    2019-11-29 20:45:22    2019-11-29 20:45:22
C9 1A 26 26    2019-11-30 18:30:33    2019-11-30 18:30:33
44 A7 28 26    2019-12-02 16:54:28    2019-12-01 16:54:28
3A 16 2A 26    2019-12-03 19:00:10    2019-12-02 19:00:10

BD 5D 4C 26    2019-12-29 19:02:21    2019-12-28 19:02:21
9F 0E 4F 26    2019-12-31 20:01:35    2019-12-30 20:01:35
25 60 50 26    2020-01-01 20:01:41    2020-12-31 20:01:41
12 03 53 26    2020-01-03 20:01:22    2020-01-02 20:01:22

24 ED 77 26    2020-01-31 20:01:40    2020-01-30 20:01:40
C2 3E 79 26    2020-02-01 20:02:10    2020-01-31 20:02:10
21 82 7A 26    2020-02-02 19:01:53    2020-02-01 19:01:53

46 D7 9C 26    2020-02-28 20:02:14    2020-02-27 20:02:14
DE 28 9E 26    2020-02-29 20:02:38    2020-02-28 20:02:38
A1 C0 A4 26    2020-03-05 20:03:45    2020-03-02 20:03:45
32 12 A6 26    2020-03-06 20:04:02    2020-03-03 20:04:02
```

From the result, looks like the timestamp is number of seconds of 31 days every month.
So my question is if there any way I can get the correct date?
I can do python.

Comment: How do You perform calculations, share the code please.

Comment: how do you derive the 'Expected Date'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deciphering hex coded timestamp from a fingerprint machine (zkemkeeper/ZEM560)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62828838/deciphering-hex-coded-timestamp-from-a-fingerprint-machine-zkemkeeper-zem560)

Comment: @MrFuppes i got it from gui..

Comment: ok seems like you might have to determine iteratively if the month changes from one that has <31 days to one that has 31 days and subtract a day (or more for Feb->Mar) in that case

Comment: thanks for your reply @MrFuppes, I wonder if you have any idea how to determine the month changes iteratively if we only have the hex timestamps without knowing the expected date?

Comment: jep, that's a pretty difficult one... you could try to determine the epoch by assuming the counter counts 12*31 days for each year and start from there - which basically means writing sort-of a calendar module. I'd also ask the manufacturer of the device if they have any advice.

Comment: I am sorry Mr @ipj but i did not see ant answer there.